# Migrating @ResponseBody to ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, response, spring-restcontroller

I have an old controller with a method that returns an object as json and marked with @ResponseBody.

The problem is that the status code is always 200, although sometimes it isn't.

The current method signature is:

```
public MyResponse myMethod(){}
```

and I want to change it to:

```
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> myMethod(){}
```

All of that is not a problem, but I afraid that it clients that use this controller will fail to parse the response. Is that possible? do Spring wraps the response with another object?

Comment: No it doesn't. The response will be the same.

Comment: No. The client will not have any issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the javadoc for @RequestMapping (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html), the body of the ResponseEntity will be unwrapped and written to the response output stream. So the output should be the same.

Documentation for the current release (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types) says essentially the same thing.

Comment: This is still correct, but you're citing docs from nearly a decade ago.

Comment: Could we update the answer to change the link to the most up-to-date version of the documentation in this case ? (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Comment: The current javadoc for @RequestMapping doesn't mention ResponseEntity

Answer (score 0):

Controller will return http 200 if it executes without exception. 
If you return ResponseEntity object with [HttpStatus.OK](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#OK) it should work.